# I can't find and disable AWS resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My free AWS tier is going to expire in 8 days. I removed every EC2 resource and elastic IP associated with it. Because that is what I recall initializing and experimenting with. I deleted all the roles I created because as I understand it, roles permit AWS to perform actions for AWS services. And yet, when I go to the billing page it shows I have these three services that are in current usage.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvKZc.png

I used the script as recommended by AWS documentation to check for all instances and it shows "no resources found".

Link for script: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager-automation-runbooks/latest/userguide/automation-awssupport-listec2resources.html

I tried searching for each service using the dashboard and didn't get anywhere. I found an S3 bucket, I don't remember creating it but I deleted it anyway, and still, I get the same output.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What about any any EBS volumes, RDS snapshots, ECR images, S3?? What exactly are you being charged for?

Comment: I recommend you to go to the billings detail page, any bill must be in detail with any service you will pay for, so that will give you a clue about it

Comment: I've updated the post to include a link to a screenshot showing the billing details. The services it mentions are Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud, AWS Key Management Service, and Amazon Simple Storage Service.

Comment: Based on that picture of your bill, just delete data from S3 and delete Amazon EBS disk volumes.

Comment: If you have no EBS volumes or S3 buckets anymore, then you won't be charged for them.  That screenshot is showing you how much of each you used, now necessarily how much you're going to use tomorrow.

Comment: A couple of more services showed in my billing since my post. I know I don't have any instances active, I'm a bit confused. I'm going to follow @AnonCoward tip and will wait and see if they charge me or not. I've also reached out to AWS support for assistance, I will post any update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I was able to get in touch with AWS support via Live chat, and they informed me that those services in my billing were usages generated before the services were terminated. AWS support was much faster than I expected.